# Excel lookup by text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to make lookup for excel table using the text in the columns 
For example if i have

A1          | A2

BMW-X6               |    1

BMW-X5          | 1

Mazda-1         | 2

Mazda-2         | 2

Mazda-3         | 2

Mercedes-Benz   | 3

Mercedes- cls   | 3

I want where there is Bmw in A1 the value is 1 in a2, and so on, any help ?

Thanks,
Morad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"BMW","Mazda","Mercedes"},A2)),0),"")
```

Add more manufacturers as required.

Must be entered as an array formula in B2 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(NOT(ISERR(FIND("BMW",A1))),1,IF(NOT(ISERR(FIND("Mazda",A1))),2,IF(NOT(ISERR(FIND("Mercedes",A1))),3,"Unknown")))`

Continue the pattern, replacing the last `[Value if False]` if you want to add additional find criteria.

Also, note that this is case sensitive.